# Count posts by date for all users

Tags: mysql

I have `users` and `posts` table and would like to get a count of posts by a user for various date spans.

```
users: id, username
1, bob
2, sam

posts: id, user_id, created (datetime)
1, 1, 2012-12-01 00:00:00
2, 1, 2012-12-30 00:01:00
3, 1, 2012-12-30 01:00:00
4, 2, 2012-12-12 00:00:00
5, 2, 2012-12-30 01:00:00
```

I want to count the posts for the last `hour`, `day` and month. Can this be done in one query?

Say the date the query is run is `2012-12-30 01:30:00` I would want something like the following:

```
User.id | hour | day | month
1       | 1    | 2   | 3
2       | 1    | 1   | 2
```

I have tried to something like the following but the numbers are wrong.

```
SELECT 
    User.id, 
    COUNT(Hour.id) as hour, 
    COUNT(Day.id) as day, 
    COUNT(Month.id) as month
FROM user as User
LEFT JOIN posts as Hour ON 
    (posts.user_id = user.id AND posts.created >= '2012-12-30 00:30:00')
LEFT JOIN posts as Day ON 
    (posts.user_id = user.id AND posts.created >= '2012-12-29 01:30:00')
LEFT JOIN posts as Month ON 
    (posts.user_id = user.id AND posts.created >= '2012-11-30 01:30:00')
```

I end up with strange numbers like

```
User.id | hour | day | month
1       | 12   | 12  | 12
2       | -    | 2   | 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
select
  username,
  user_id,
  sum(created>=date_sub('2012-12-30 01:30:00', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) hour,
  sum(created>=date_sub('2012-12-30 01:30:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) day,
  count(*) month
from users inner join posts on users.id=posts.user_id
where created>=date_sub('2012-12-30 01:30:00', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
group by user_id
```

(you can then substitute the specific datetime `'2012-12-30 01:30:00'` with `now()`)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking this might be a way of doing it. Will try it out and report back.

Comment: @dogmatic69 you're welcome! Anyway, there's something to fix in your solution (aliases, and missing group by) but it should work, but you have to make sure that you use Distinct clause `count(DISTINCT Hour.ID)` otherwise rows will be multipied, that's why you get strange results

Comment: Tried out what you have and it seems to work. Will write some tests to make sure but seems correct so far.